# Iterate over enum items in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

How do I iterate over enum items in TypeScript? I tried for-in, but this iterates over strings. I need to call a function for each enum value.

```
for (const foo in FooType) {
    // here I have error that string is not assignable to parameter of type FooType
    this.doCalculation(foo)
}


private doCalculation(value: FooType): void {
   // some logic
}
```

enum `FooType` looks like this:

```
export enum SupportedFiat {
  VALUE_A = 'VALUE_A',
  VALUE_B = 'VALUE_B',
  VALUE_C = 'VALUE_C'
}
```

Comment: You can do either as @Mark Skelton mentioned or you can simple iterate over the array(Enum type) by doing `this.doCalculation(FooType[foo])`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using `for of` and `Object.values`.

```
for (const value of Object.values(FooType)) {
  // here I have error that string is not assignable to parameter of type FooType
  doCalculation(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enums are translated to this type of object:

```js
"use strict";
var SupportedFiat;
(function (SupportedFiat) {
    SupportedFiat["VALUE_A"] = "VALUE_A";
    SupportedFiat["VALUE_B"] = "VALUE_B";
    SupportedFiat["VALUE_C"] = "VALUE_C";
})(SupportedFiat || (SupportedFiat = {}));
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAymAO8D2AnALsAJgMQJYEM0oBvAKCigDUBBAGQFUBRAfWqgF4oByGhl6rgBpyVOk2YAhDt17iJQkbJYBhaTzEqupAL5A)

unfortunately, Typescript enums don't really implement an iterator for easy iterating so you need to make your own:

```
function* supportedFiatValues(): IterableIterator<SupportedFiat> {
    yield SupportedFiat.VALUE_A;
    yield SupportedFiat.VALUE_B;
    yield SupportedFiat.VALUE_C;
}

for (const supportedFiat of supportedFiatValues()) {
// ...
}
```

You *could* use `Object.values()` but you'll lose type information there, IMHO the generator approach brings you better type inference.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to contribute my solution to this problem as I recently went on a hunt to have a function to be able to iterate my enums for display purposes. I ended up designing my own which loses no typing information:

```
function getEnums<T extends {[key: string]: number | string}>(enumType: T): Array<[key: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]]> {
  const keys = Object.keys(enumType).filter(key => isNaN(Number(key)));
  return keys.map(key => [key, enumType[key] as T[keyof T]]);
}
```

it adds some safety so that not just any ol' object can be passed and returns the key as string literals of the valid keys and the value as the enum.

usage:

```
for (const [_, foo] of getEnums(FooType))
  doCalculation(foo);

function doCalculation(foo: FooType): void { }
```